# I cant get two HTML modals to show with CSS, JavaScript, and PHP

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble trying to get two different modals to show with two different buttons.  On my actual website the buttons just show the incorrect modal but when I put it into an standalone HTML document we see the result is much different.  One of the modals is showing on the screen before anyone hits a button and the second one shows with both button presses

Here is my standalone HTML Code

Any help is much appreciated, even a comment could help.  I have about 3 hours into this problem ftr.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif} 
            h1 {font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif,}
            .mySlides {display: none}
            p { 
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 60px;
                margin-top:0px;
             }

             .background {
                position: relative;
                text-align: center;
                color: white;
            }

            .centered {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
              }

              /* The Modal (background) */
            .modal {
                display: none; /* Hidden by default */
                position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
                z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
                padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%; /* Full width */
                height: 100%; /* Full height */
                overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
                background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
            }

            /* Modal Content */
            .modal-content {
                background-color: #fefefe;
                margin: auto;
                padding: 20px;
                border: 1px solid #888;
                width: 80%;
            }

            /* The Close Button */
            .close {
                color: #aaaaaa;
                float: right;
                font-size: 28px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            .close:hover,
            .close:focus {
                color: #000;
                text-decoration: none;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            </style>
        </head>
    <body>
        <button class="bar-item button padding-large hover-red hide-small right" id="myBtnL">Login</button>
        <button id="myBtn" class="bar-item button padding-large hover-red hide-small right">Register</button>

    <div id="myModalL" class="modalL">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="closeL">&times;</span>
        <p>some text in the L modal</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script>
// Get the modal
var modalL = document.getElementById('myModalL');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btnL = document.getElementById("myBtnL");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("closeL")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btnL.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
</html>

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far what I see is that you had the class 'modal' written as 'modalL' on one of your modals. You've also got some other names done incorrectly - please check my revised example.

```js
// Get the modal
var modalL = document.getElementById('myModalL');



// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btnL = document.getElementById("myBtnL");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementById("close");
var spanL = document.getElementById("closeL");


// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}


// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btnL.onclick = function() {
    modalL.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
spanL.onclick = function() {
    modalL.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif} 
h1 {font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif,}
.mySlides {display: none}
p { 
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-top:0px;
 }

 .background {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
  }



  /* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <button class="bar-item button padding-large hover-red hide-small right" id="myBtnL">Login</button>
        <button id="myBtn" class="bar-item button padding-large hover-red hide-small right">Register</button>

    <div id="myModalL" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span id="closeL" class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>some text in the L modal</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span id="close" class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>

</html>

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh look, another typo

Comment: and one gets a 150K rep on SO by answering only the toughest of questions, eh?

Comment: @AECapuano I'm not sure if there are other problems with your code, does the code I fixed work for you?

Comment: In the demo It ran well with no problems showing the modals early but then I realized both buttons show the same modal.  @Stacey Reiman

Comment: let me look again ok? I'll see if I can find what the problem is there.

Comment: @Stacey Reiman Thanks,  I will look as well and post a solution if found.

Comment: @AECapuano should be fixed now! This could be cleaned up - I'd be happy to rework it for you a bit. I added IDs to the close buttons, and added some other changes to your JS - but honestly this could be written cleaner and more DRY :)

Comment: @Stacey Reiman SUCCESS!!!! I will be implement and reviewing the changes, I would love to know how to clean it up.  Thank you

Comment: Ok I have to make kids dinner, but will take a look at cleaning this up for you after ok? Happy I was able to help somebody :)

Comment: @Stacey Reiman Your help was much appreciated, you have probably saved me a few hours.  Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif} 
            h1 {font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif,}
            .mySlides {display: none}
            p { 
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 60px;
                margin-top:0px;
             }

             .background {
                position: relative;
                text-align: center;
                color: white;
            }

            .centered {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
              }

              /* The Modal (background) */
            .modal {
                display: none; /* Hidden by default */
                position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
                z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
                padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%; /* Full width */
                height: 100%; /* Full height */
                overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
                background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
            }

            /* Modal Content */
            .modal-content {
                background-color: #fefefe;
                margin: auto;
                padding: 20px;
                border: 1px solid #888;
                width: 80%;
            }

            /* The Close Button */
            .close {
                color: #aaaaaa;
                float: right;
                font-size: 28px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            .close:hover,
            .close:focus {
                color: #000;
                text-decoration: none;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            </style>
        </head>
    <body onload="myFunction()">
        <button class="bar-item button padding-large hover-red hide-small right" id="myBtnL">Login</button>
        <button id="myBtn" class="bar-item button padding-large hover-red hide-small right">Register</button>

    <div id="myModalL" class="modalL">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="closeL">&times;</span>
        <p>some text in the L modal</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script>
// Get the modal
var modalL = document.getElementById('myModalL');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btnL = document.getElementById("myBtnL");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("closeL")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btnL.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";

    }
}
function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("myModalL").style.display = 'none';
}

</script>
</html>

</script>
</html>
```